# CREATE TABLE AS with geometry in SpatiaLite

Tags: sql, spatialite, sqlite

I would like to create a new SpatiaLite table based on a command.

For example, I would like to transform a table to a different coordinate system:

```
SELECT Transform(Geometry, 3068) FROM points_berlin;
```

To create a new table I would do this in PostGIS:

```
CREATE TABLE points_berlin_3068 AS
SELECT Transform(Geometry, 3068) FROM points_berlin;
```

Although this creates the table and the table has as many rows as the input table it is not a spatial table. How do I get the geometry to show up in the new table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SpatiaLite requires you to explicitly register geometry columns in its ecosystem (updating metadata, adding triggers) using the provided [management functions](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html#p16); SQLite does not support automatic detection like with PostgreSQLs *type-modifier* system.

Having created a new table as you specified you should be able to 'spatially enable' it with

```
SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('points_berlin_3068', 'geometry', 3068, 'POINT', 'XY');
```

Comment: RecoverGeometryColumn is unchanged but this is a newer document about SpatiaLite functions: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.0.html.

Comment: @user30184 Thx.! I use to look up the most commonly compiled version in QGIS.

Comment: Interesting workflow, thank you! Worth noting: pay attention to how you name the new geometry colum, as its default name is the command you executed! If you execute the command as I did, you would have to subsequently run
*SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('points_berlin_3068', 'Transform(Geometry, 3068)', 3068, 'POINT', 'XY');* since the geometry column is now named *Transform(Geometry, 3068)*. To avoid this you can use an alias in the original select command: *CREATE TABLE points_berlin_3068_newest AS SELECT Transform(Geometry, 3068) AS Geometry FROM points_berlin;*

Answer (score 1):

I find thast using RecoverGeometryColumn adds the record to geometry_columnns, and also allows QGIS to read the table.  However, ArcGIS cannot read the geometries in the table.  Still looking for a way to issue a CREATE TABLE AS statement and have it be a valid table that other GIS products can read.